# How to Achieve a Grooveshark-like Widget as Facebook Link?

Tags: html, facebook, flash, facebook-opengraph, grooveshark

I post a link to Grooveshark on Facebook like `http://grooveshark.com/s/Toothpaste+Kisses/3gGocy?src=5` and get a seemingly normal result (link to another page) yet once clicked, it transforms into a Flash widget like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCpoY.png) (the URL to the SWF is https://grooveshark.com/facebookWidget.swf?songID=249422).

My question is *how is this achieved?*  I know you can add all sorts of special Open Graph data to a page but is this some kind of special deal the company has going on with Facebook?  Can anyone illuminate this mystery because it would be very useful to understand.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Grooveshark developer here. We don't have a special deal with FB. I don't remember exactly how we set that stuff up but it is all using open graph. You should be able to see all the open graph related tags if you disable javascript redirects in your browser and go to a song URL like the one you posted above, then view source (or just use wget to download the file).

Comment: Do you link to a video player SWF or does Facebook take care of that?

Comment: The swf is ours. I believe we specify the embed code somewhere in the open graph tags.